# Mostrar numeros impares de una lista de numeros aleatorios PHP

Tags: php, html

Necesito mostrar una lista con 50 números aleatorios comprendidos entre el 100 y el 300, y de esos números, mostrar solo los números impares. La resolución debe de ser lo más sencilla posible, pero no encuentro la idea o forma de coger esos numeros aleatorios de la función `rand(100,300);` y hacer sobre ellos un IF, ya que si los pongo como variable siempre van a ser los mismos números.

Este es el código que llevo hasta ahora que genera los números aleatorios.

```
<?php
$i = 1;
do {
 echo rand(100,300);
 echo "<br>";
 (++$i);
} while ($i < 51);
?>
```

¿Cómo podría mostrar solos los impares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conocer si un número es par o impar, utilizamos el operador «%» para calcular el «resto» de la división del número entre «2». Si el número tiene resto igual a cero sabemos que es par y sino es impar.

Por lo que con un simple if haciendo dicha operación te podría resultar

```
<?php
$i = 1;
do {
 $numero = rand(100,300);
 if ($numero%2 != 0){
    echo $numero;
    echo "<br>";
 }
 (++$i);
} while ($i < 51);
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirve de lujo. Me podrías comentar también para qué sirve ! = 0? Por si es 1 que lo muestre no?

Comment: te recomiendo que te mires los operadores relacionales http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/cursoJava/fundamentos/introduccion/operadores1.htm